# Implementing Central Authentication System with angular4 apps using django session authentication

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework, single-sign-on, cas

I have three different django projects, `ProjectA`, `ProjectB` and `ProjectC`. `ProjectA` is django website but other two are only `django-rest-framework` api based projects and have `angular4` apps that consumer these apis respective to their projects.

Now I need to combine their Users and some other functionality and need to put into `ProjectA`. So if a user is logged into `ProjectA`, and visit angular app of `ProjectB` or `ProjectC` and user should already be considered logged in.

So this is certain that I need SSO and also I need to replace the token authentication of angular app with session authentication and I am thinking of using Central authentication System `CAS` but I don't understand how `angular4` apps will be served alongside `django` using its session authentication and consuming its api. because right now all three projects and those two angular apps are deployed on different domains or subdomains.

Can you help out here. Also please comment on any security flaws or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Angular` apps can be put behind `django` application. So user will only be able to load application when he/she is logged in. Otherwise user will be redirected to `CAS` login page. Here is the list of things that you need to do in order to achieve `CAS` session authentication with django rest framework.

**1.** You need to make angular dist and put it somewhere in the project, add the path to `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `TEMPLATE` in settings.py.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    "frontend/dist/",
]
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            'frontend/dist/'
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**2.** RUN `collectstatic` command in order to collect all `js bundles`.

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

**3.** You will also need to edit the `index.html` file in dist folder in order to support django static files. I am posting mine.

```
<!doctype html>
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Blank</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <my-root></my-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'runtime.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'polyfills.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'styles.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'vendor.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'main.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**4.** Final step is the url configuration. So you need to use `login_required` decorator with `TemplateView`.

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

import django_cas_ng.views as cas_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', login_required(TemplateView('index.html').as_view())),
    url(r'^api/', include('api.urls')),
    url(r'^polls2/', include('polls2.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', cas_views.login, name='cas_ng_login'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', cas_views.logout, name='cas_ng_logout'),
    url(r'^accounts/callback/$', cas_views.callback, name='cas_ng_proxy_callback'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Hope this helps.